# nmap version 7.60 failing to compile with yocto version 2.4 (rocko)

Tags: yocto, bitbake, nmap

I am using Yocto 2.4 (Rocko) build system to make a minimal filesystem. I am facing a problem while compiling **nmap** package.

nmap bb file: [path_upto_sources]/sources/meta-security/recipes-security/nmap/**nmap_7.60.bb**

Below are the command and its output. The nmap package is failing to compile. Please help.

**TOOLCHAIN_PATH=/opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/ MACHINE=am335x-evm bitbake nmap**

```
NOTE: Started PRServer with DBfile: /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/cache/prserv.sqlite3, IP: 127.0.0.1, PORT: 46813, PID: 5985
Loading cache: 100% |#####################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00
Loaded 4470 entries from dependency cache.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.36.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "ubuntu-16.04"
TARGET_SYS           = "arm-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE              = "am335x-evm"
DISTRO               = "arago"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "2018.08"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "arm armv7a vfp thumb neon callconvention-hard"
TARGET_FPU           = "hard"
meta-arago-distro    
meta-arago-extras    = "rocko:b47d8b4a5687d66b918903a6f7f9fec7e315cf13"
meta-browser         = "HEAD:26d50665e2f7223c5f4ad7481a8d2431e7cb55fb"
meta-qt5             = "rocko:682ad61c071a9710e9f9d8a32ab1b5f3c14953d1"
meta-networking      
meta-python          = "rocko:c8d10c4663ac76cbc13702ba6ff9cf5b4583c9de"
meta-perl            = "rocko:baff0d6c267a9955611622ae98d9136a98d202c7"
meta-oe              
meta-gnome           = "rocko:c8d10c4663ac76cbc13702ba6ff9cf5b4583c9de"
meta-ti              = "rocko:bd9fc96232042ae8d830056dfe7a8811d658a7a4"
meta-linaro-toolchain 
meta-optee           = "rocko:75dfb67bbb14a70cd47afda9726e2e1c76731885"
meta-java            = "rocko:fbe0b0eb30d93f5fa2101fb015f20c1dc118b4a6"
meta-iot-cloud       = "rocko:28617184390005c6d23123f6ed51123a6dff8574"
meta-security        = "rocko:74860b2b61afd033fba130044ae66567ead57aaf"
meta-maker           = "rocko:d3df9412a4e4540317fc934aba02857bae82c6e1"
meta                 = "rocko:56a0fad9a4b2360984b5b6829452a6f4353aeb20"

Initialising tasks: 100% |################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
ERROR: nmap-7.60-r0 do_install: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: nmap-7.60-r0 do_install: Function failed: do_install (log file is located at /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/temp/log.do_install.18563)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/temp/log.do_install.18563
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing python function extend_recipe_sysroot
| NOTE: Direct dependencies are ['virtual:native:/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/sources/oe-core/meta/recipes-devtools/pseudo/pseudo_1.8.2.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/sources/oe-core/meta/recipes-devtools/gnu-config/gnu-config_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/sources/oe-core/meta/recipes-devtools/quilt/quilt-native_0.65.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/sources/oe-core/meta/recipes-devtools/libtool/libtool-native_2.4.6.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/sources/oe-core/meta/recipes-connectivity/libpcap/libpcap_1.8.1.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/sources/oe-core/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python_2.7.15.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/sources/oe-core/meta/recipes-devtools/libtool/libtool-cross_2.4.6.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/sources/oe-core/meta/recipes-devtools/automake/automake_1.15.1.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/sources/oe-core/meta/recipes-devtools/autoconf/autoconf_2.69.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/sources/meta-linaro/meta-linaro-toolchain/recipes-devtools/external-linaro-toolchain/external-linaro-toolchain.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/sources/oe-core/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python-native_2.7.15.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/sources/oe-core/meta/recipes-devtools/pkgconfig/pkgconfig_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot']
| NOTE: Installed into sysroot: []
| NOTE: Skipping as already exists in sysroot: ['pseudo-native', 'gnu-config-native', 'quilt-native', 'libtool-native', 'libpcap', 'python', 'libtool-cross', 'automake-native', 'autoconf-native', 'external-linaro-toolchain', 'python-native', 'pkgconfig-native', 'xz-native', 'texinfo-dummy-native', 'readline', 'sqlite3', 'bzip2', 'gdbm', 'openssl', 'zlib', 'libffi', 'db', 'm4-native', 'openssl-native', 'sqlite3-native', 'db-native', 'expat-native', 'gdbm-native', 'bzip2-native', 'readline-native', 'zlib-native', 'gettext-minimal-native', 'ncurses', 'opkg-utils', 'cryptodev-linux', 'cryptodev-linux-native', 'makedepend-native', 'pigz-native', 'ncurses-native', 'util-macros-native', 'xproto-native']
| DEBUG: Python function extend_recipe_sysroot finished
| DEBUG: SITE files ['endian-little', 'bit-32', 'arm-common', 'arm-32', 'common-linux', 'common-glibc', 'arm-linux', 'arm-linux-gnueabi', 'common']
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_install
| NOTE: make -j 6 DESTDIR=/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/image install
| Compiling libnetutil
| cd libnetutil && make
| Compiling liblinear
| Compiling libpcre
| make[1]: Entering directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/liblinear'
| make[1]: 'liblinear.a' is up to date.
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/liblinear'
| Compiling libnbase
| cd nbase && make
| make[1]: Entering directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/libpcre'
| Compiling libdnet
| make  all-am
| make[1]: Entering directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/libnetutil'
| make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/libnetutil'
| Compiling liblua
| make[1]: Entering directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/libdnet-stripped'
| make[1]: Entering directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/nbase'
| make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/nbase'
| make[2]: Entering directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/libpcre'
| Making all in include
| make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/libpcre'
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/libpcre'
| cd ndiff && /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/python-native/python setup.py install --prefix "/usr" --install-lib="/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages" --root "/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/image"
| make[1]: Entering directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/liblua'
| make[1]: 'liblua.a' is up to date.
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/liblua'
| make[2]: Entering directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/libdnet-stripped/include'
| make  all-recursive
| make[3]: Entering directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/libdnet-stripped/include'
| Making all in dnet
| make[4]: Entering directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/libdnet-stripped/include/dnet'
| make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
| make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/libdnet-stripped/include/dnet'
| make[4]: Entering directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/libdnet-stripped/include'
| make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/libdnet-stripped/include'
| make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/libdnet-stripped/include'
| make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/libdnet-stripped/include'
| Making all in src
| make[2]: Entering directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/libdnet-stripped/src'
| make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
| make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/libdnet-stripped/src'
| make[2]: Entering directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/libdnet-stripped'
| make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all-am'.
| make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/libdnet-stripped'
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/libdnet-stripped'
| Compiling libnsock
| cd nsock/src && make
| make[1]: Entering directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/nsock/src'
| make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/nsock/src'
| cd ncat && make
| running install
| Compiling nmap
| rm -f nmap
| arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++  -march=armv7-a -marm -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard --sysroot=/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/recipe-sysroot -Wl,-E  -L/opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf//arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf//arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Lnbase -Lnsock/src/   -o nmap charpool.o FingerPrintResults.o FPEngine.o FPModel.o idle_scan.o MACLookup.o nmap_dns.o nmap_error.o nmap.o nmap_ftp.o NmapOps.o NmapOutputTable.o nmap_tty.o osscan2.o osscan.o output.o payload.o portlist.o portreasons.o protocols.o scan_engine.o scan_engine_connect.o scan_engine_raw.o scan_lists.o service_scan.o services.o TargetGroup.o Target.o targets.o tcpip.o timing.o traceroute.o utils.o xml.o nse_main.o nse_utility.o nse_nsock.o nse_dnet.o nse_fs.o nse_nmaplib.o nse_debug.o nse_pcrelib.o nse_lpeg.o main.o -lnsock -lnbase libpcre/libpcre.a -lpcap    libnetutil/libnetutil.a ./libdnet-stripped/src/.libs/libdnet.a ./liblua/liblua.a ./liblinear/liblinear.a -ldl
| make[1]: Entering directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/ncat'
| running build
| running build_py
| make[1]: Entering directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/nping'
| Compiling liblua
| running build_scripts
| running install_lib
| creating /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/image/usr
| creating /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/image/usr/lib
| creating /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/image/usr/lib/python2.7
| creating /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/image/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
| copying build/lib/ndiff.py -> /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/image/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
| byte-compiling /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/image/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ndiff.py to ndiff.pyc
| make nping
| make[2]: Entering directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/liblua'
| make[2]: 'liblua.a' is up to date.
| make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/liblua'
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/ncat'
| cd ncat && make install
| make[2]: Entering directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/nping'
| make[1]: Entering directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/ncat'
| running install_scripts
| creating /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/image/usr/bin
| copying build/scripts-2.7/ndiff -> /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/image/usr/bin
| Compiling liblua
| changing mode of /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/image/usr/bin/ndiff to 755
| running install_data
| creating /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/image/usr/share
| creating /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/image/usr/share/man
| creating /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/image/usr/share/man/man1
| copying docs/ndiff.1 -> /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/image/usr/share/man/man1
| running install_egg_info
| make[2]: 'nping' is up to date.
| make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/nping'
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/nping'
| cd nping && make install
| make[2]: Entering directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/liblua'
| make[2]: 'liblua.a' is up to date.
| make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/liblua'
| Installing Ncat
| mkdir -p -m 755 /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/image/usr/bin /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/image/usr/share/man/man1
| /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/hosttools/install -c -c -m 755 ncat /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/image/usr/bin/ncat
| make[1]: Entering directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/nping'
| /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/hosttools/strip -x /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/image/usr/bin/ncat
| /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/hosttools/strip: Unable to recognise the format of the input file `/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/image/usr/bin/ncat'
| Makefile:168: recipe for target 'install' failed
| make[1]: *** [install] Error 1
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/ncat'
| Makefile:419: recipe for target 'install-ncat' failed
| make: *** [install-ncat] Error 2
| make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
| /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/hosttools/install -c -d /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/image/usr/bin /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/image/usr/share/man/man1
| /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/hosttools/install -c -c -m 755 nping /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/image/usr/bin/nping
| /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/hosttools/strip -x /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/image/usr/bin/nping
| /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/hosttools/strip: Unable to recognise the format of the input file `/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/image/usr/bin/nping'
| Makefile:127: recipe for target 'install-nping' failed
| make[1]: *** [install-nping] Error 1
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/nmap-7.60/nping'
| Makefile:419: recipe for target 'install-nping' failed
| make: *** [install-nping] Error 2
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| WARNING: /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/temp/run.do_install.18563:1 exit 1 from 'exit 1'
| ERROR: Function failed: do_install (log file is located at /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/Yocto/source/tisdk/build/arago-tmp-external-linaro-toolchain/work/armv7ahf-neon-linux-gnueabi/nmap/7.60-r0/temp/log.do_install.18563)
ERROR: Task (/home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/yocto/tisdk/sources/meta-security/recipes-security/nmap/nmap_7.60.bb:do_install) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 723 tasks of which 714 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
NOTE: Writing buildhistory

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/sunny/Projects/Siemens/yocto/tisdk/sources/meta-security/recipes-security/nmap/nmap_7.60.bb:do_install
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: The environment is using "host" systems "strip" command to strip the binary. You need to setup the external toolchain environment to pick the correct "strip".

Comment: @Parthiban TOOLCHAIN_PATH=/opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/  isn't enough to set up the external toolchain environment, if not, what should be done?

Comment: https://elinux.org/images/c/c8/ExternalToolchainsInYocto.pdf As the presentation is old you need to refer the recent variable names from yocto manual.

Comment: export PATH=/opt/gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin:$PATH. Adding toolchain binaries to path variable also didn't solved my problem.

Comment: Did you set "EXTERNAL_TOOLCHAIN" variable? ELT_TARGET_SYS? TCMODE? You may need TCMODE = "external-arago" and so on.

Comment: If I remove nmap as a required package from core-image-minimal bitbake file the whole file system compiles successfully. So I don't think there is any need to set any other variables. It has to do with nmap bitbake file.